# Include log4j.xml in Project Jar

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, log4j

Does anyone know how I can bundle my log4j.xml file when I build my project Jar and how I can load the file at run time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to load your log4j.xml file at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a log4j.xml in a jar just like any other file, and it's loaded according to Log4J's [initialization rules](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit).

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, you should put your log4j.xml file to default package in your JAR file.